# Every morning Timers.Timer is late for 2-5 seconds

Tags: c#, timer

I have a `System.Timers.Timer` which is used for scheduling some tasks run. I have two `BlockingCollection` queues that are waiting for timer to fire and put some tasks to the queues:

```
private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{
   Logger.WriteTrace("Timer elapsed", "Timer elapsed after waiting: "+ DateTime.Now);
   lock (globalLock)
   {
      if (!_stop)
      {
         Logger.WriteTrace("Timer elapsed", "Iterating through schedules");
         DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
         foreach (T schedule in schedules)
         {
            DateTime occurence = schedule.GetNextOccurrence(now);
            if ((occurence - now).TotalMilliseconds < DefaultDelay)
            {
               Logger.WriteTrace("Run times", "Task added to the queue");
               priorityDictionary[schedule.IsParallel].Add(schedule);
            }
         }

         double nextWake = CalcualteNextWake(DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(DefaultDelay));
         SetInterval(nextWake);
      }
   }
}
```

In SetInterval method I have

```
if (interval > 0)
{
   _timer.Interval = interval;

   // starting timer, cause by design it is not Autoreset
   Logger.WriteTrace("Setting next wake after: ",
      interval.ToString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval));

   _timer.Start();
}
else
{
   Logger.Error("Wrong interval");
}
```

So I noticed weird behavior of the timer, every day the last log message that is written says smth like this:

```
12:37:59##Trace####Setting next wake after: ##78839662.0084 at 5/27/2014 10:31:58 AM##
```

And every next day first message says:

```
10:32:03##Trace####Timer elapsed##Timer elapsed after waiting: 5/27/2014 10:32:03 AM##
```

Every other elapsing of the timer works well and accurate and elapses exact same time it said in "setting next wake" message, so timer is late only first run each day and always between 2-5 seconds. I cannot find anything that can be an issue in the code, seems like it works well, and I don't have any problems with the during the day timer elapsing. Does anybody have some ideas on what can be the cause of this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here, but you should really use UtcNow. Or does your code tolerate the clock jumping around two times a year?

Comment: The operating system doesn't treat your program very kindly when it doesn't execute code for a long period.  Just about every memory page will be swapped out of RAM.  Loading it back from DLL files and the paging file can take a while.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: usr: I should use UtcNow, that's true.

Comment: Hans Passant: i thought about that, but is there a way to avoid it? or to ask the OS to behave it how i need? 5 seconds delay is long as for timer, i think OS should handle this somehow.

Comment: If the program is active every few seconds there should be no paging out. Also, if there is no memory pressure you'll see close to zero latency when activating a portion of the program that is only active once per day. *Is* there memory pressure?

Comment: We have no good lead yet what the problem is. My suggestion: Create a dead-simple program that reproduces the issue. Let it run over night. See if you can reproduce it. In the process you might discover the problem. If you can't reproduce it with a simple program you know it's your fault and not the OS'es. That's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your code you use **DateTime.Now** in Logger.WriteTrace.

Why not create one variable and use it like

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

Logger.WriteTrace("Timer elapsed", "Timer elapsed after waiting: "+ now);
```

And also in SetInterval method

```
Logger.WriteTrace("Setting next wake after: ",
      interval.ToString() + " at " + now.AddMilliseconds(interval));
```

Comment: This is not answer to my question and I changed it just to be able to know the operation time of adding to the queue, just in case.